# How do I know when I can/should use `with` keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

In C#, when an object implements `IDisposable`, `using` should be used to guarantee that resources will be cleaned if an exception is thrown. For instance, instead of:

```cs
var connection = new SqlConnection(...);
...
connection.Close();
```

one needs to write:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    ...
}
```

Therefore, just by looking at the signature of the class, I know exactly whether or not I should initialize the object inside a `using`.

In Python 3, a similar construct is `with`. Similarly to C#, it ensures that the resources will be cleaned up automatically when exiting the `with` context, even if a error is raised.

However, I'm not sure how should I determine whether `with` should be used or not for a specific class. For instance, [an example from `psycopg`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) doesn't use `with`, which may mean that:

- I shouldn't either, or:
- The example is written for Python 2, or:
- The authors of the documentation were unaware of `with` syntax, or:
- The authors decided not to handle exceptional cases for the sake of simplicity.

In general, how should I determine whether `with` should be used when initializing an instance of a specific class (assuming that documentation says nothing on the subject, and that I have access to source code)?

Comment: Maybe this recommendation in the PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) can clear a bit your doubt: _When a resource is local to a particular section of code, use a with statement to ensure it is cleaned up promptly and reliably after use_

Comment: You [can use](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html?highlight=statement#with-statement) both `connection` and `cursor` as context managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regarding when you *should* use it:

No one forces you to use the `with` statement, it's just syntactic sugar that's there to make your life easier. If you use it or not is totally up to you but, it is generally recommended to do so. (We're forgetful and `with ...` looks ways better than explicit initialize resource/finalize recourse calls).

#### When you *can* use it:

When you *can* use it boils down to examining if it defines the context manager protocol. This could be as simple as trying to use `with` and seeing that it fails :-)

If you dynamically need to check if an object *is* a context manager, you have two options.

First, wait for the stable release of `Python 3.6` which defines an `ABC` for context managers, `ContextManager`, which can be used in `issubclass/isinstance` checks:

```
>>> from typing import ContextManager
>>> class foo:
...     def __enter__(self): pass
...     def __exit__(self): pass
... 
>>> isinstance(foo(), ContextManager)
True
>>> class foo2: pass
... 
>>> isinstance(foo2(), ContextManager)
False
```

Or, create your own little function to check for it:

```
def iscontext(inst):
    cls = type(inst)
    return (any("__enter__" in vars(a) for a in cls.__mro__) and
            any("__exit__" in vars(a) for a in cls.__mro__))
```

As a final note, the `with` statement is present in `Python 2` and in `3`, the use case you saw probably just wasn't aware of it :-).

Answer (score 2):

`with` is for use with context managers.
At the code level, a context manager must define two methods:

- `__enter__(self)`
- `__exit__(self, type, value, traceback)`.

Be aware that there are class decorators which can turn otherwise simple classes/functions into context managers - see [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/contextlib.html) for some examples

Answer (score 0):

You should use `with` whenever you need to perform some similar action before and after executing the statement. For example:

- *Want to execute SQL query?* You need to open and close the connections safely.Use `with`.
- *Want to perform some action on file?* You have to open and close the file safely. Use `with`
- *Want to store some data in temporary file to perform some task?* You need to create the directory, and clean it up once you are done. Use `with`, and so on. . .

Everything you want to perform before the query execution, add it to the `__enter__()` method. And the action to be performed after, add it to the `__exit__()` method.

One of the nice thing about `with` is, *`__exit__` is executed even if the code within `with` raises any `Exception`*